# не отрабатывает шрифт в браузерах

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, google-fonts

Написан вот такой код, использую бутстрап

```
<h1>WE MAKE WEBSITES</h1>

h1 {
    margin: 0px 0 10px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'Raleway ExtraLight';
    color: white;
    padding-top: 285px;
    }
```

Подключаю так

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
```

отображается в итоге так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать ссылку на шрифт в таком виде:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200
```

Где `200` - это жирность начертания шрифта.

В вашей ссылке только стандартное начертание.

На сайте Google Fonts, прежде чем копировать ссылку, выберите необходимые начертания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует подключать его как стили CSS.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

На примере шрифта 'Roboto'